# Code signing issue with Sparkle auto-update

Tags: cocoa, sparkle

I am using [Sparkle](http://sparkle-project.org/) for the first time, and having troubles getting things off the ground. When I check for updates, it correctly detects a newer version, downloads it, unarchives it, and then gives the following error:

> Update Error!
>   An error occurred while extracting the archive. Please try again later.

The output log shows the following detail:

```
Sparkle: The appcast item for the update has no DSA signature.
The update will be rejected, because both DSA and Apple Code
Signing verification failed.
```

My archive is named "MyApp.pkg.zip", and contains only "MyApp.pkg". It has an apple ID digital signature. I verified this by downloading the zip manually, extracting it, running the PKG, and clicking the lock icon on the first install page.

[image: hi]

The PKG has been created using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html).

My appcast has the following:

```
    <enclosure url="http://thedomain/MyApp.pkg.zip" sparkle:version="1.0.0.990" length="5752133" type="application/octet-stream" />
```

My .app also has the same Apple ID signature as the .pkg, though I don't think it matters at this point of the auto-update process.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong? How is Sparkle concluding that the digital signature is not sufficient, when the PKG is clearly digitally signed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different certificates for signing the .app and the .pkg? When you go to create the certificate on Apple's Certificates site, you have to choose one or the other type.

You need to have two certificates, one for signing the .app and one for signing the .pkg.